# 'list' object has no attribute 'title' When trying to print text

Tags: python

```
cars = []
cars.append('toyota')
cars.append('honda')
cars.insert(1, 'ford')
bad_car = cars.pop(1)
print('The worst car on this list is a ' + bad_car.title() + ".")
pricey = 'honda'
cars.remove(pricey)
print('\nA ' + pricey.title() + ' is too expensive')
print(cars)
print('\nA ' + cars.title + ' is just right')
```

Seem to get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title', every time. Trying to get the console to print: *A Toyota is just right*

Comment: Typo: change to `print('\nA ' + "".join([car.title() for car in cars]) + ' is just right')`

Comment: What is `cars`?  What are you trying to do with `cars.title`?

Answer (score 0):

when you call bad_car you are calling a str. Then you can do bad_car.title().

But `cars` is a list.
You need to do `print('\nA ' + cars[0].title() + ' is just right')`

Answer (score 0):

It is because `cars` is a `list` object, not a `string` like `pricey`. That's why `pricey` has a `method` called `title`, while `list` objects do not. So to get your answer correct you'd need to `access` the string `toyota` that is inside of the list `cars`. To do that you just need to use this syntax:
`just_right = cars[0]` to access the first index of the list `cars`, which is just here `toyota`, after what you can then do your syntax:
`print('\nA ' + just_right.title() + ' is just right')`

**Summary**:

`...
print(cars)
just_right = cars[0]
print('\nA ' + just_right.title() + ' is just right')`